# How to express gratitude as a house guest?

Tags: mandarin, taiwanese

How would the following sentence come across as a part of a thank you letter to a family receiving you as a guest in their home in Taiwan? The letter is to be sent before arriving as a "thank you in advance" gesture.

謝謝你們接待我當你們的家庭成員

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an approach that's formal, more "literary chinese":

**對府上之款待﹒先行拜謝**

"先行拜謝" is, roughly "thank you in advance"

"府上" is the honourable term of "your home", you may change it to "貴府", "貴寓", or "尊府

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000038602

"款待" is, roughly "reception"

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000078380

Comment: The literary version seems much better suited to the situation. Would it be advisable, when writing the letter, to use the traditional orientation (i.e. Top to bottom, right to left)?

Comment: sure, if you can. btw, you mean real writing by hand, or type and print it?

Comment: Yes, real writing by hand... It's actually the strongest aspect of my Chinese language skills. A fellow student saw one of my character practice sheets and remarked, "Wow, those look just like the ones in the book." I was pleased with myself... until the teacher asked me to speak, that is.

Comment: great, remember to write in traditional chinese, it's a must, for your situation. btw, there're "canned" openings & endings in letter; need any guides?

Comment: Sure, I'd love some guides. Social/Cultural nuances are the most difficult part of the language to me. I'll take all the help I can get.

Comment: for "canned" openings & endings, google "尺牘用語". download this dictionary, read p726-p768; grasp the ideas, have fun :)

https://archive.org/details/englishchinesedi00kwon

Answer (score 0):

ALso another way to express your gratitude as an house guest you can say：
叔叔和阿姨，谢谢让我留在您们的家。